# How to install an R library using R CMD

Tags: c++, r

To use *dictionary learning* and *sparse coding* methods, I am trying to install *SPArse Modeling Software (spams)* package in R. Their instruction says:

1. Download the .tar.gz file.
2. After `Un-tar`ing the file and entering the newly extracted folder, run the following command:

   ```
   R CMD INSTALL --html -l \$R\_LIBS spams
   ```

In my case, I use

```
R CMD INSTALL --html -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library spams
```

But I receive the following error messages:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:593:1: error: 
>         **templates must have C++ linkage**
>
> Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:594:20: error: 
>         explicit specialization of non-template struct '__static_assert_test'

There are many other error messages which highlight some parts of the library codes (like the second error message) which seem to have the same root cause.

*I am not sure if it helps but just in case,* I am using `Command Line Tools (OS X 10.11) Xcode 8 beta 6`.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. It's buggy code.  Likely mixes C and C++ headers inside/outside of `C "extern"` blocks.

That uses to pass with older compilers.  It does not more.  You'll probably have to do some minor surgery on it -- helps if you know C(++) and R package structures.

So in short, it is not your use of `R CMD INSTALL ...` which is at fault here but rather the package you are trying to install.  There is a reason we all prefer R software from CRAN as these issues have then been ironed out...